# Display a <div> only on % or px page scroll: css only?

Tags: html, css, scroll, menu

I would like to display a `<div>` but only when user scroll down, for example when he reaches 800px down. I would like to keep the things simple and light so CSS only would be the best option :) It's to display some small `<li>` based right sticky menu.

I found the solution to stick it to the right but not to display only on certain height scroll.

Thanks!

Comment: nope. you'll need javascript

Comment: damn it! this was what I thought

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you get how much the body has scrolled. In this example as soon as you scroll past 800 px the button will appear

```js
$(document).scroll( function(evt) {
    var scrollAmount = $(window).scrollTop();
    var documentHeight = $(document).height();
    
    if(scrollAmount > 800) {
   $('button').css("visibility","visible");
 }
});
```

```css
div{
  height:1200px;
  background-color:red;
  width:100%;
}
button{
  visibility:hidden;
  position:absolute;
  top:900px;
  left:50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  </div>
<button>Appear</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use wow library :

http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/

You can pick your animation when showing from here :

https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: OK thanks I'll do some custom JS and use animate.css. Thanks!